# SQL categorize table values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi all I have an issue related to my SQL table `tbl_myTable` and values like

```
rollid  | Name    | fileName
------------------
1       | aaaa    | 
2       | bbbb    |
3       | cccc    |
4       | dddd    |
5       | eeee    |
6       | ffff    |
7       | gggg    | 
8       | hhhh    |
9       | iiii    |
10      | jjjj    |
11      | kkkk    |
12      | llll    |
```

I need to categorize these values to 5 items block and then I need to update a `fileName` field in to each block like book1,book2,book3...etc. ie only 5 record exists in each book and my expected output look like

```
rollid  | Name    | fileName
------------------
1       | aaaa    | book1
2       | bbbb    | book1
3       | cccc    | book1
4       | dddd    | book1
5       | eeee    | book1
6       | ffff    | book2
7       | gggg    | book2
8       | hhhh    | book2
9       | iiii    | book2
10      | jjjj    | book2
11      | kkkk    | book3
12      | llll    | book3
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify if you need to base your "book groups" on the rollId or the name. I'm assuming it's the name since you said rollId might skip some values. If not you can easily swap out the order in the row_number() window function to correct it:

```
with tbl_myTable_mimic as (
    select 1 as rollid, 'aaaa' as name, '' as filename
    union select 2 as rollid, 'bbbb' as name, '' as filename
    union select 3 as rollid, 'cccc' as name, '' as filename
    union select 4 as rollid, 'dddd' as name, '' as filename
    union select 5 as rollid, 'eeee' as name, '' as filename
    union select 6 as rollid, 'ffff' as name, '' as filename
    union select 7 as rollid, 'gggg' as name, '' as filename
    union select 10 as rollid, 'hhhh' as name, '' as filename
    union select 11 as rollid, 'iiii' as name, '' as filename
    union select 12 as rollid, 'jjjj' as name, '' as filename
    union select 13 as rollid, 'kkkk' as name, '' as filename
    union select 15 as rollid, 'llll' as name, '' as filename
), j as (
    select 
        *
        , row_number() over (partition by 1 order by name asc, rollid asc) as rn
    from tbl_myTable_mimic 
), i as (
    select 
        *
        , 'book' + cast(((rn-1)/5)+1 as varchar(16)) as newFileName
    from 
        j 
)
select * from i
```

Comment: And if you need to update the existing table, just swap out the last select statement with an `update tbl_myTable from tbl_myTable mt join i on ...`

Comment: Thank you @Giscard let me check

Comment: Why PARTITION BY 1? PARTITION BY is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
update myTable 
set filename = 'book' + CAST((id / 6) + 1 as varchar)
```

**Update**

```
update a
set a.filename = 'book' + CAST((b.rownumber / 6) + 1 as varchar)
from myTable a
left join 
(
select id , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by id) as rownumber 
from myTable
) b
on a.id = b.id
```

I don't know how to sort your rows. but i think you can change the `order by id` to fit your pattern.

Comment: but in my table there is 35000 rows and roll id is not an order ie some roll id missing.

Comment: @RER I see , if so i think you need use ROW_NUMBER() to general a order column and then join your table to use the above way.   I try to write a sample to you.

Comment: Thank you @shenhengbin me also trying to the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @T table
(
  rollid int primary key,
  Name varchar(10),
  fileName varchar(10)
)

insert into @T(rollid, Name) values
(1,        'aaaa'),
(2,        'bbbb'),
(3,        'cccc'),
(4,        'dddd'),
(5,        'eeee'),
(6,        'ffff'),
(7,        'gggg'),
(8,        'hhhh'),
(9,        'iiii'),
(10,       'jjjj'),
(11,       'kkkk'),
(12,       'llll')

update T
set filename = 'book'+cast((rn + 4) / 5 as varchar(10))
from 
  (
    select filename,
           row_number() over(order by rollid) as rn
    from @T
  ) as T
```

Got a silent downvote on this one so I **guess** an explanation on my part is required.

I use [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in a derived table to generate an unbroken series of integers that can be used to calculate the book number by dividing with 5. In SQL Server it **is** possible to run an update statement against a derived table which means that there is no need to join the result back to the table.

Those of you who are still in doubt can try it out on [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64150)

Answer (score 0):

```
update tbl_myTable set fileName ='book1' where rollid < 6
update tbl_myTable set fileName ='book2' where rollid between 7 and 10
update tbl_myTable set fileName ='book3' where rollid >10
```

Comment: but in my table there is 35000 rows and roll id is not an order ie some roll id missing.

Comment: +1 for sheer laziness, although I think the OP wanted a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try out with following query:

```
 UPDATE tbl_myTable
SET fileName='book' + (1 + (CAST( (CAST(rollid AS INT) - 1) / 5) AS INT))
```